# Can't call a static method in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, class, static

I have a simple class containing a static attribute. There are two static methods in this class: one to get the static attribute and the other to initialize it. Yet when call the static method the compiler reports an error.

The class:

```cpp
class Sudoku {
    Cell Grid[9][9];
    int CurrentLine;
    int CurrentColumn;

    void deleteValInColumn(int val, int col);
    void deleteValInRow(int val, int row);
    void deleteValInBox(int val, int x, int y);
    static int unsetted; //!
public:
    static void IniUnsetted() { //!
        unsetted = 0;
    }
    static int GetUns() { //!
        return unsetted;
    }
    Sudoku(ini InitGrid[9][9]);
    void Calculate_Prob_Values();
    Cell getCell(int x, int y);
    QVector<int> getPossibleValues(int x, int y);
    bool SolveIt();
};
```

This is the error I get:

```
In member function 'bool Sudoku::SolveIt()':
no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
In function `ZN6Sudoku6GetUnsEv':
undefined reference to `Sudoku::unsetted` error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Try putting `unsetted` in the `cpp` file: `int Sudoku::unsetted = 0`

Comment: You'll probably find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/1782465).

Comment: @Angew: that is way too broad a thread for this issue.

Comment: @AdriC.S.: no, that is unnecessary. It is zero initialized by default!

Comment: @LaszloPapp Well, the answer to the OP's question is the last point in the second answer to the Q I posted.

Comment: @LaszloPapp It may be zero-initialised, but it still **needs a definition** in a .cpp file, which the OP obviously doesn't provide. So the `= 0` is unnecessary, but the definition itself it needed.

Comment: @Angew: which is exactly what my answer does now as well. The initialization is still unnecessary to suggest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to define the static variable, even if it is not initialized explicitly. That is what is missing in your code. You should have provided a simple example to reproduce the issue, but for your convenience I am providing one which works.

#### main.cpp

```
class Foo {
    public:
        static int si;
        static void bar();
};

int Foo::si = 0; // By default, it will be initialized to zero though.

void Foo::bar() {
     Foo::si = 10;
};

int main()
{
    Foo::bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Note: I would suggest to get someone to review your code because "unsetted" is incorrect English. If we are at it, you would probably need to fix your indentation as well.

Comment: If I'm wrong, then explain [this](http://ideone.com/oyLOag), please. It's not about initialisation, it's about a definition. Non-const static class members need one, period.

Comment: This work just fine 
Note : initialization and definition should be in .CCP file . Thank you all . شكرا

Comment: @LaszloPapp Now, no problem (note that I've long since removed the downvote). See my comment 17 mins ago.

Answer (score 5):

In your code there is no definition of `unsetted`, there is only declaration.

The solution is to put somewhere in your cpp file a line like this:

```
int Sudoku::unsetted
```

The reason for that is that each instantiation of `Sudoku` class will use the same `unsetted` member so it cannot be defined for each of them, so it's up to programmer to define it in one place only.

Answer (score 2):

In your cpp file, define the static variable (ideally with an initialization):

```
int Sudoku::unsetted = 0;
```

Comment: The problem is not in the initialization . the problem is in the definition it self . thank you the problem is solved .

Answer (score 2):

If you are declaring any static variable in class, then you should define that variable outside the class also.

Example:

```
class A
{
    public:
    static int x;    // declaration
};

int A::x;            // definition
```

Comment: It's not "defining" and "initialize," but "declaring" and "define."